# Every button changes at once in listview builder but i want to operate specifically or single how can i do that?

Tags: flutter, radio-button, iconbutton

Every button changes at once in listview builder  but i want to operate specifically or single  how can i do that?

[This is what happens GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y69wP.gif)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("ListView.builder")),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: radioDetails.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Card(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(radioDetails[index].name),
              trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    (isPlaying) ? Icons.stop : Icons.play_arrow,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      isPlaying = !isPlaying;
                    });
                    isPlaying == true
                        ? audioPlay(radioDetails[index].url)
                        : audioPause();
                  }),
            ),
```

Comment: Do you want it to play 2 or 3 at once or if one is playing another should stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have the `isPlaying` state inside the stateful widget which builds the listview. So that one state is applied to all buttons.

You need to control the state for each list item separately.

You might include it into your `radioDetail` object.

(Guessing what your `RadioDetail` class might look like...)

You can add the `isPlaying` attribute here.

```dart
class RadioDetail {
  final String url;
  final String name;
  bool isPlaying = false;

  const RadioDetail(this.url, this.name);
}
```

Then in your `onPressed` write:

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  setState(() {
    radioDetail[index].isPlaying = !radioDetail[index].isPlaying;
  });
```

And the same thing with your icon:

```dart
icon: Icon(
  (radioDetail[index].isPlaying) ? Icons.stop : Icons.play_arrow,
  ),
```